# Efficient Eigen Matrix SubIndexing + Concatenation

Tags: c++, matrix, indexing, eigen, eigen3

I'm using Eigen for easy optimization of some of my matrix math. I'm currently trying to make the following operation more efficient:

Given Matrix A:

```
1, 2, 3 
4, 5, 6
```

Matrix B:

```
7, 11, 13, 19, 26, 7, 11
8, 9,  15, 6,  8,  4, 1
```

and "index map" column vector IM:

```
0, 1, 3, 6
```

I'd like to append the columns of Matrix B mapping to the indexes in IM, to Matrix A as such:

```
1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 19, 11
4, 5, 6, 8, 9,  6,  1
```

I'm currently able to do this with a massive for loop, but this is the bottleneck in my code and I'd like to avoid this:

```
#pragma unroll
for (int i = 0; i < 25088; i++) {
    block.noalias() += _features.col(ff[i]);
}
```

I've seen the discussion here and poured over the docs but can't seem to figure out the right syntax relating to Eigen matrices: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=329

Any thoughts/tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the experimental fork linked to at [this comment](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=329#c26) of the bug you linked to?